# Generation of RTE_Components.h

Tags: c, embedded, keil

I'm working with MDK-Pro and the File System library.

In my application, I require an SPI interface to the SD card. I've managed to setup the project properly, except that in the `RTE_Components.h` file that Keil generates the line `#define RTE_Drivers_MCI0` which subsequently triggers a preprocessor error ("SDIO not configured in RTE_Device.h").

Although I can manually comment out this line in `RTE_Components.h`, every so often Keil updates this file and I get the above problem. Does anyone know what exactly generates this file, and how I can stop it from adding the SDIO-related definitions into the project?

Answer (score 0):

The RTE_Components.h is not supposed to be modified and will always be automatically generated. That the stack tries to connect via MCI interface is related to your configuration made in the "FS_Config_MC_0.h".

```
//   <o>Connect to hardware via Driver_MCI# <0-255>
//   <i>Select driver control block for hardware interface
#define MC0_MCI_DRIVER          0

//   <o>Connect to hardware via Driver_SPI# <0-255>
//   <i>Select driver control block for hardware interface when in SPI mode
#define MC0_SPI_DRIVER          0

//   <o>Memory Card Interface Mode <0=>Native <1=>SPI
//   <i>Native uses a SD Bus with up to 8 data lines, CLK, and CMD
//   <i>SPI uses 2 data lines (MOSI and MISO), SCLK and CS
//   <i>When using SPI both Driver_SPI# and Driver_MCI# must be specified
//   <i>since the MCI driver provides the control interface lines.
#define MC0_SPI                 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Sivar. Unfortunately, I have also set `MC0_SPI` to 1 to use SPI mode, but the `RTE_Components.h` still seems to define `RTE_Drivers_MCI0`! I'm using Keil uVision 5.10.0.2 and the MDK-Middleware.5.1.4

Comment: Which MCU device are you using?

Comment: I'm using the `STM32F405RGT6`